# Question about lifecycle methods definition

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I learning Android about 6 month, and all this time i described Lifecycle methods like some kind of callback, which "trigerred" when OS change state or configuration.

Questions:

---

1) For example, User rotate the screen. As i think, Android invoce some interface and Activity runing it's code when callback come. I'm not sure about it, because i got throw documentation(Activity/Window/...classes) and i did't find this interface or smth like it. What's really happen when user rotate the screen?

---

2) For example, user push the button on his mobile app and create new Activity. Lifecycle methods will be called, but OS state or configuration was't change. It means, my definition of lifecycle methods is wrong. How to describe it correctly? Help me to understand what's wrong with my first definition.

---

I know about this link:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

And there is a line:

`The Activity class provides a number of callbacks that allow the activity to know that a state has changed...`

But inside Activity class i see, for example:

```
@MainThread
@CallSuper
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

and i have not see `override` word, so how Activity can implement it? 
There is `@CallSuper` annotation, but parent classes(include Context) have no code connected with lifecycle. So it this real callbacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure that I understand your question, because it is vague, but let me try to address the 2 specific examples:

> 1) For example, User rotate the screen. As i think, Android invoce
>   some interface and Activity runing it's code when callback come. I'm
>   not sure about it, because i got throw
>   documentation(Activity/Window/...classes) and i did't find this
>   interface or smth like it. What's really happen when user rotate the
>   screen?

In the usual case, when the user rotates the screen, a "configuration change" occurs. Android responds to this by killing off the currently active `Activity`. Android calls the "lifecycle methods": `onPause(), onStop()` and `onDestroy()` on the current `Activity`. Android then creates a new instance of the `Activity` and calls the "lifecycle methods": `onCreate(), onStart()` and `onResume` on that instance.

In case the application has declared that it wants to handle the configuration change itself (by specfying `android:configChanges="..."` for the `Activity` in the manifest), Android **does not** kill the `Activity` when the screen is rotated. Instead, Android calls the "lifecycle method": `onConfigurationChanged()` on the current `Activity`.

> 2) For example, user push the button on his mobile app and create new
>   Activity. Lifecycle methods will be called, but OS state or
>   configuration was't change. It means, my definition of lifecycle
>   methods is wrong. How to describe it correctly? Help me to understand
>   what's wrong with my first definition.

The "lifecycle methods" do not only refer to changes int he OS state or configuration. "Lifecycle methods" are also called to inform your `Activity` about changes in the state of the `Activity` itself. `onCreate()` is called to inform the `Activity` that a new instance of the `Activity` has just been created by Android and that the `Activity` should initialize itself. `onResume()` is called to inform the `Activity` that it is now the current `Activity` that the user will see (topmost `Activity` in its task and visible on screen). `onPause()` is called to inform the `Activity` that another `Activity` is going to become the current `Activity`. `onConfigurationChanged()` is called to inform the `Activity` that a configuration change has occured on the device (this can be one of many differnt things including: locale, screen size, screen density, screen orientation, keyboard presence, etc. There are many other "lifecycle methods" that are called by Android at specific times during the lifetime of an `Activity`.